# How to make a search based on get_field_gender label?

Tags: django

Well, this might be a bit odd, but I was wondering if it is possible to make a search based on the label for choiceFields rather than the stored database value.
I have an app that when the user searches for a vehicle of type `truck`, the query can't retrieve results because the value stored in the database is `tru`, although choiceField label is `truck`. The same goes for gender `female` is `fem`, for example.

I could go around this problem with alternative ways, but I was wondering if Django had this implemented somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider changing the search functionality to search with the shortened name. You can still display the label on the front-end: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#Examples

Comment: The front-end display is fine, it can be achieved with `get_field_display()`. Well, I will assume there is no way and find a workaround. Thanks.